# File Not Found in the directory

Tags: python, csv

File Not found when i should already copy that file to the directory

I already tried to copy that file in various folders like Include etc

```
import numpy as np
import collections
a=np.genfromtxt('Desktop\a.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=str)
print(a)
```

All the data that is in the file

Comment: Because your file path is wrong.  File kept on Desktop generally has following path structure for windows `C:/Users/username/desktop/a.csv`

Comment: import numpy as np
import collections
a=np.genfromtxt("a.csv",delimiter=',',dtype=str)
print(a)

Comment: What if i copy my file to scripts in the projects

Comment: Then just give the filename like `np.genfromtxt('a.csv',)`

Comment: Not working as i put code in the comment see that

Comment: import numpy as np
import collections
a=np.genfromtxt('a.csv')
print(a)

Comment: See this i put the code

Comment: If you have new information, edit your question.  Code doesn't format in comments well.

Comment: import numpy as np                                                                                                            import collections                                                                                                            a=np.genfromtxt('a.csv')                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                
if i put my file in the scripts folder

Answer (score 2):

`\a` is an escape sequence like `\n`.  In this case, it is the [BEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) character.  Escape the backslash (`\\a`), use a raw string to suppress escape code translation (`r'Desktop\a.csv'`) or use forward slashes.

Note you are also using a *relative* path, meaning you have to run the code from the directory in which "Desktop" is a sub-directory.  Use a full path to make sure you get it on the desktop, which will include your username like `'c:/users/garauv/desktop/a.csv'` or whatever your real username is.